# Authentication Issue with WP-API and Net::Http

Tags: ruby, oauth, wordpress, net-http

I am new to Wordpress. I want to access WP-API to create a post using REST API. I am unable to perform POST, PUT and Delete request. Though I can retrieve data only. I wrote a ruby script for this. Below is my code snippet.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'net/http/oauth'
require 'json'

class CollectScript
  def initialize
    uri = URI.parse('http://vagrant.local/wp-json/wp/v2/posts')
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
    req.basic_auth("admin", "password")
    res = http.request(req)     
    puts res.body
  end
end
CollectScript.new
```

While running the above code I am getting following error:

```
{"status":"error","error":"You need to login with a user capable of creating posts."}
```

Using the same code with `GET` request I am able to get the posts JSON. But for `HTTP POST` request I need to pass authentication. I tried with basic authentication and Oauth too. But same result.

Please can anyone help me to figure out the issue with authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply install this [basic_auth plugin](https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth) in my Wordpress site.

- First, I download the zip file from [this](https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth) link
- Now extract it to /content/plugins folder in your project directory
- Activate this plugin from your wp-admin interface.
- Now I use the following code snippet for authentication

  ```
  uri = URI.parse("http://vagrant.local/wp-json/wp/v2/posts")
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
  req.basic_auth("admin", "password")
  req.set_form_data({title: "Another 11new post", status: "publish", content_raw: "this is the content of the post", excerpt_raw: "Excerpt", post_media: ['/uploads/rails.png']})
  res = http.request(req)   
  puts res.body
  ```

Now It successfully works.

Answer (score 1):

The [wp-api gem](https://github.com/colinyoung/wp-api) claims to do what you want, by providing a ruby wrapper for the WP REST API. I am not sure if (or how) is it working as I have not tried it myself. At the very least it could give you some pointers on how to handle the connections by looking at its source code.

Specifically, at https://github.com/colinyoung/wp-api/blob/master/lib/wp/api/client.rb#L36 you can see how the author is retrieving a resource while performing basic authentication **in one step**:

```
Client.get(path, basic_auth: { username: @user, password: @password })
```

Bear in mind that this gem uses `HTTParty` which provides the `get` method for `Client`.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't find any useful resource on your suggested gem.

Comment: Did you try to use the gem? It supports post/user retrieval as well as basic authentication and metadata retrieval. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Also edited my answer to point exactly how the gem's author is treating resource retrieval and basic auth.

Comment: Instead of using basic authentication, can we use Oauth in one step using this gem? Because basic authentication is not suitable for production environment.